# facebook registration birthday mysql returning 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, facebook, date-format

I have 1 problem to fix with my facebook registration plugin for a website.
im trying to insert the birthday into the db, facebook format is dd-mm-yyyy...im getting a result 0000-00-00,

```
<code>
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(facebook, 
                          email, 
                          username, 
                          country, 
                          gender, 
                          dob,
                          password, 
                          profile, 
                          activated, 
                          ip)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'images/default_profile.png', 1,  ? 

$data = array($fbId, $register['email'],
                     $register['username'],
                     $location,
                     $register['gender'],
                     $register['birthday'],
                     md5($register['password']),
                     $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
             );
```

any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly format the date. In one of my previous [tutorials](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-facebook-registration-plugin-as-your-registration-system/15/), I used something like this (hopefully it's still working):

```
$fb_birthday = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime($fb_birthday));
```

Comment: Cheers man this solution worked perfect:)...iv tried to vote up, but it tells me i need 15 reputations:(...

Comment: It's fine, glad it helped! ;)

Comment: Lol, i just got up to 16 reps:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for MySQL you have to submit it as a string in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, if it's not it's treated as in invalid entry and the field gets set to '0000-00-00'  Convert it in php before sending.   If you're sure of the format from Facebook is always  dd-mm-yyyy  I'd just explode the string on the dash separator and rearrange the order of values.

```
$fbDate =  $register['birthday'];
$dateArray = explode("-", $fbDate);

$newDate = $dateArray[2]."-".$dateArray[1]."-".$dateArray[0];
```

Then use the $newDate in your data array for the prepared statement.

```
$data = array($fbId, $register['email'],
                 $register['username'],
                 $location,
                 $register['gender'],
                 $newDate,
                 md5($register['password']),
                 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
         );
```